# Include joined table records by a specific query, if any

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, subquery, sequelize.js

Let's assume that I want to select an `Author`, `include`ing their books published in `1942` (one author has many books).

I tried doing this:

```
Author.findOne({
  where: {
    name: "Alice"
  },
  include: [{
    model: Book,
    where: {
      year: 1942
    }
  }]
}).then(authorAndTheirBooks => { ... })
```

`authorAndTheirBooks` is going to be `null` if there is no `Book` published in `1942`. What I'd like to have is to get an empty array as `books` (if none was matched) and get the array of books if there are books published by Alice in 1942 (which already happens).

If I remove that filter, it works fine.

How to solve this? To fetch the author, including their books, which were published in `1942`?